# Use output from services to controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I want to result of my $http.get from my service to my controller.

myserviceSample.js

```
  function messagesService($q,$http){
    var messages;
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://api.com/feedback/list'
    })
    .then(function success(response){

      messages = response.data;
      console.log(messages);
    },function error(response){
      console.log('error'+ response);
    });
    console.log(messages);

    return {
      loadAllItems : function() {
        return $q.when(messages);
      }
    };
  }

})();
```

mycontrollerSample.js

```
  function MessagesController(messagesService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.messages = [];

    messagesService
      .loadAllItems()
      .then(function(messages) {
        console.log(messages);
        vm.messages = [].concat(messages);
      });
  } 
})();
```

The above code results gives undefined output.
What i miss?

Comment: Just a comment on how you are preparing the service.  it looks like you are making the call to retrieve feedback/list when the service is instantiated.  I would consider this bad, the call should be made when the request for information comes i.e. when loadAllItems is called.  Also I would remove the  function wrapper from the return object and place all the functionality in one function called loadAllItems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$q.when` object does expect `promise/object` to make it working. In your case you have to pass `promise` object to `$q.when` as you are doing `$http.get` call. Here `messages` object doesn't hold promise of `$http.get`, so you could change the implementation of method like below.

**Service**

```
function messagesService($q,$http){
    var messages = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://api.com/feedback/list'
    })
    .then(function success(response){
       return response.data;
    },function error(response){
       return $q.reject('Error Occured.');
    });

    return {
      loadAllItems : function() {
        return $q.when(messages);
      }
    };
}
```

Then controller will resolve that promise & `.then` will do the trick

```
function MessagesController(messagesService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.messages = [];
    messagesService
      .loadAllItems()
      .then(function(messages) {
        console.log(messages);
        vm.messages = [].concat(messages);
      });
}
```

> **Note:** Using `$q` to create a custom promise, is considered as bad pattern when you have `$http.get` method there(which does return
>   promise itself)

**Improved Implementation**

```
function messagesService($q, $http) {
  var messages, getList = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://api.com/feedback/list'
    })
    .then(function success(response) {
      messages = response.data
      return response.data;
    }, function error(response) {
      return $q.reject('Error Occured.');
    });
  };

  return {
    loadAllItems: function() {
      if (!data)
        return getList(); //return promise
      else
        return $q.resolve(messages); //return data
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: @artemist do look at updated version of code.. Glad to help you.. Thanks :)